# Need to construct interface/pointer using Reflect in Golang, not working

Tags: go

So, this works:

```
house := model.House {};
err = db.First(&house).Error;
```

However, this doesn't work:

```
var house model.House;

fetchFromDatabase := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(house)).Interface();
err = db.First(&fetchFromDatabase).Error;
```

... **The database library gives the error:**

> unsupported destination, should be slice or struct

To me, that should be a struct, considering the "House" type is a struct. However, I'm still wrapping my head around `Reflect` ... can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The library is complaining because the application is passing a `*interface{}` to the method. The value `fetchFromDatabase` is a pointer to a struct. Pass this value directly to the method:

```
var house model.House
fetchFromDatabase := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(house)).Interface()
err = db.First(fetchFromDatabase).Error
```